# Angular provider must return a value from $get factory method

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, proj4js

So I have a problem with my angular factory that I've been trying to solve for a while now. I guess my knowledge in angular isn't quite enough here.

Most of the code I will post here is reused code from another part of the solution that I didn't write. So that's probably the reason why I can't figure this out.
Also this is the first ever factory I've made.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('app.coordinate-transformer-service', [])
    .factory('coordinateTransformerService', coordinateTransformerService);

coordinateTransformerService.$inject = ['proj4js', 'gmaps'];

function coordinateTransformerService(proj4js, gmaps, objectsEpsgCode) {

    var factory = {};

    factory.$get = ['proj4js', function coordinateTransformerFactory(proj4js) {
        return new coordinateTransformerService(proj4js, gmaps, objectsEpsgCode);
    }];

    var mapProjection = 'EPSG:4326', // WGS84 latlong
            objectsProjection = 'EPSG:' + objectsEpsgCode,
            transformCoordinatesToLatLng = function (point) {
                if (objectsProjection === mapProjection) {
                    return new gmaps.LatLng(point.y, point.x);
                }

                var newPoint = {
                    x: point.x,
                    y: point.y
                };
                proj4js.transform(new proj4js.Proj(objectsProjection), new proj4js.Proj(mapProjection), newPoint);
                return new gmaps.LatLng(newPoint.y, newPoint.x);
            };

    factory.transformLatLngToProject = function (latlng) {
        if (!factory.isFunction(latlng.lng) || !factory.isFunction(latlng.lat)) {
            throw new Error("No functions lat() or lng() exists on parameter latlng");
        }

        var newPoint = {
            x: latlng.lng(),
            y: latlng.lat()
        };

        proj4js.transform(new proj4js.Proj(mapProjection), new proj4js.Proj(objectsProjection), newPoint);
        newPoint = roundPointsToCorrectDecimals(newPoint);

        return newPoint;
    };

    factory.roundPointsToCorrectDecimals = function (point) {
        var noDecimals = objectsEpsgCode === 4326 ? 5 : 0;

        if (!point || !point.x || !point.y) {
            throw new Error("Point, x or y is null or not defined");
        }

        return {
            x: point.x.toFixed(noDecimals),
            y: point.y.toFixed(noDecimals)
        };
    };

    factory.isFunction = function (functionToCheck) {
        var getType = {};
        return functionToCheck && getType.toString.call(functionToCheck) === '[object Function]';
    };

    return factory;
};

//coordinateTransformerService.prototype = {
//    constructor: coordinateTransformerService
//};
//return coordinateTransformerService;
})();
```

I get the error "Provider 'proj4js' must return a value from $get factory method."
And to be honest I don't know what the factory.$get function I have does. That is part of the code I didn't write. 
Proj4js is a library that convert coordinates from one system to another.
So we load objects in from the server to display them on a google map, and some of that don't use latitude longitude. So that is why we need to transform them with proj4js. If that info would help anyone.

But I know a factory method needs to return an object. But am I not doing that already?
Maybe it is that factory.$get function that is the problem, as I've said I don't know the purpose of it... But removing it doesn't help^^

Also, don't mind that it's called coodinateTransformerService and not coordinateTransformerFactory. I used a service first, just didn't care to rename it until I got it to work.

**EDIT:** This may help. In angular.js where the error is thrown:

```
function enforceReturnValue(name, factory) {
return function enforcedReturnValue() {
  var result = instanceInjector.invoke(factory, this, undefined, name);
  if (isUndefined(result)) {
    throw $injectorMinErr('undef', "Provider '{0}' must return a value from $get factory method.", name);
  }
  return result;
};
}
```

result gets undefined. Name is proj4js and factory is this which a colleague made:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('blocks.proj4js').factory('proj4js', proj4jsFactory);

proj4jsFactory.$inject = ['$window'];
function proj4jsFactory($window) {
    return $window.proj4js;
}
})();
```

Comment: What point in the code actually gets that error as a response? It looks like something is supposed to call a get method but isn't or is supposed to have a get method but doesn't.

Comment: @Anthony not sure what you mean with your question, but I agree on the other things you said. Mikalai removed the $get function all together in his answer.

Comment: Your question indicates that you are seeing "Provider 'proj4js' must return a value from $get factory method", but it's not really clear in your example code what the context of that error is. There is some point in some code that results in that error. It would be useful to know 1) what code is trigger the error (either copied from your actual code, or if you are pretty sure the issue is on the other end, a simple one or two line example of code that should work but gets that response), and 2) what specific code on the other end appears to be throwing the error instead of a valid response.

Answer (score 1):

As I see you mixed up the service and provider. The easiest way to meet your needs will be:

```js
angular.module('app.coordinate-transformer-service', [])
    .service('coordinateTransformerService', CoordinateTransformerService);

CoordinateTransformerService.$inject = ['proj4js', 'gmaps', 'objectsEpsgCode'];

function CoordinateTransformerService(proj4js, gmaps, objectsEpsgCode) {

    var mapProjection = 'EPSG:4326', // WGS84 latlong
            objectsProjection = 'EPSG:' + objectsEpsgCode,
            transformCoordinatesToLatLng = function (point) {
                if (objectsProjection === mapProjection) {
                    return new gmaps.LatLng(point.y, point.x);
                }

                var newPoint = {
                    x: point.x,
                    y: point.y
                };
                proj4js.transform(new proj4js.Proj(objectsProjection), new proj4js.Proj(mapProjection), newPoint);
                return new gmaps.LatLng(newPoint.y, newPoint.x);
            };

    this.transformLatLngToProject = function (latlng) {
        if (!this.isFunction(latlng.lng) || !this.isFunction(latlng.lat)) {
            throw new Error("No functions lat() or lng() exists on parameter latlng");
        }

        var newPoint = {
            x: latlng.lng(),
            y: latlng.lat()
        };

        proj4js.transform(new proj4js.Proj(mapProjection), new proj4js.Proj(objectsProjection), newPoint);
        newPoint = roundPointsToCorrectDecimals(newPoint);

        return newPoint;
    };

    this.roundPointsToCorrectDecimals = function (point) {
        var noDecimals = objectsEpsgCode === 4326 ? 5 : 0;

        if (!point || !point.x || !point.y) {
            throw new Error("Point, x or y is null or not defined");
        }

        return {
            x: point.x.toFixed(noDecimals),
            y: point.y.toFixed(noDecimals)
        };
    };

    this.isFunction = function (functionToCheck) {
        var getType = {};
        return functionToCheck && getType.toString.call(functionToCheck) === '[object Function]';
    };
};
```

Comment: Could you provide details of error? And I have just provided the concept of service.  Here can be syntax errors or inject errors too.

Comment: I guess it is an inject error: [$injector:undef] and here the error message  I wrote in my post.

Comment: I think the reason in services proj4js, gmaps, objectsEpsgCode. Please check them and it should solve the problem.

Comment: I've changed gmaps to uiGmapgooglMaps which I think it should be instead. Removed objectEpsgCode as an injection. Also check my edit, since I still get the error after that change. It may help you.

Comment: Sounds like you want to know what the difference is between services, factories, providers, etc. The short answer is that they are all versions of the same thing. Factory is a specialized version of provider, and service is a specialized version of factory. Each lets you do the same thing in less code. You can find a really high level and detailed explanation at: http://www.simplygoodcode.com/2015/11/the-difference-between-service-provider-and-factory-in-angularjs/